# Index exceeds matrix dimensions error in matlab

Tags: matlab

I get this error

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions

when I run the following in MATLAB. What am I doing wrong?

```
>> a

a =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9

>> a(:)

ans =

     1
     4
     7
     2
     5
     8
     3
     6
     9


>> sum(a(:))

Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

>> sum(a(:),1)

Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

>> sum(a(:),2)

Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

Comment: You need to indent code by four spaces in Markdown for it to be typeset properly.

Comment: It seems you have overwritten `sum` by a variable. Check by `which sum` whether it is a function (built-in) or a variable.

Comment: Try closing and re-opening Matlab and then run only the code you have posted here and see if it works. Your problem is almost definitely what @Nemesis has described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did set a variable under the name `sum`

```
a = [1 2 3 ; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
sum = 1;


>> sum(a);
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.


clear sum;
>> sum(a)

ans =

    12    15    18
```